# Intellij No java module

Tags: java

I changed sth to have Kotlin scripts available, but right now I cannot find my options to create Java Java class.
My JDK home path in Project Structure is alright "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1"

[Image Intellij no Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBZQN.png)

Comment: For me, the Java class option only appears, when doing the right click on a source folder, but not on the module folder itself (which makes sense, because a Java class outside of a source folder is useless)

Answer (score -1):

Try to create java class into src folder, u must see that option when u try to create class there